# Showing a function $\Bbb Z/5\to\Bbb Z/5$ is surjective

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

How can I prove that $f: ℤ/5 → ℤ/5$ given by $f(x) = x \cdot [2]_5$ is surjective?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  See what happens when you multiply  by $[3]_5$

Comment: The domain only has five values, make a table for it.

Answer (score 1):

Omitting the $[x]_5$ notation, i.e $x=[x]_5$

$$
0 \rightarrow 0 \\  
1 \rightarrow 2 \\
2 \rightarrow 4 \\
3 \rightarrow 6=1 \\
4 \rightarrow 8=3 \\
5 \rightarrow 10=5
$$
Thus surjective as every value gets mapped to.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking more abstractly than others: First note that $Z_5$ is a field, hence at least an integral domain - i.e there are *no zero-divisors* in the system.  Hence if $2x = 2y$ in the system, then $2 (x - y) = 0$, and so since there are no zero-divisors, necessarily $x - y = 0$, or $x = y$.  Hence the map $x \rightarrow 2x$ is one-to-one, hence onto by finiteness.  Note that this argument generalizes beyond the specific values 5 and 2.

Answer (score -1):

for injectiv, jaust look where 1,2,3,4,0 go to. for the inverse multiply the Equation with the inverse of 2
trula